# Реализация интерфейса для статического полиморфизма

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Как реализовать интерфейс так, чтобы в каждом классе должны были быть реализованы все функции из класса интерфейса?

**Нашел такое решение:**

1. Программист, который хочет задать определенный интерфейс для всех дочерних классов, составляет список обязательных функций.
2. Каждую из этих функций нужно якобы вызвать в базовом классе.
3. Не зная ничего о реализации дочерних классов, это можно реализовать с помощью хитрости - вызываем функцию через указатель.

По идее, код не должен компилироваться, если в каком-то из дочерних классов нет реализации функции из списка. Но... оно компилируется.

> Первый раз я расстроен, что мой код компилируется.

Помогите сломать компиляцию :-)

**Есть небольшие требование:** Не должно быть дополнительных вычислений в run-time

```
template <class AnyFruitType>
struct IFruit{
  void _() {
      static_cast<AnyFruitType*>(this)->foo_0();
      static_cast<AnyFruitType*>(this)->foo_1();
      static_cast<AnyFruitType*>(this)->foo_2();
    }
};

// Наследуюсь от класса-интерфейса, полагая, что в нем произойдет проверка
struct apple : IFruit<apple>{
  void foo_1(){}
  void foo_2(){}
  // void foo_3(){} делаем вид, что не реализована одна из функций
};

struct banana : IFruit<banana>{
  void foo_1(){}
  void foo_2(){}
  void foo_3(){}
};


int main() {
  apple a;
  banana b;

  a.foo_1();
  b.foo_1();
  //a.foo_3(); Код компилируется, если нет вызова нереализованной функции.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы такая проверка в базовом классе заработала, проверяющую функцию необходимо инстанцировать. Чтобы не было бессмысленных вызовов функций необходимо брать указатели на них. Зато имеет смысл делать проверку в конструкторе, чтобы он инстанцировался при генерации конструктора класса-наследкика.

```
template<typename AnyFruitType>
struct IFruit
{
    constexpr IFruit(void) noexcept
    {
        static_cast<void>(&AnyFruitType::foo_1);
        static_cast<void>(&AnyFruitType::foo_2);
        static_cast<void>(&AnyFruitType::foo_3);
    }
};
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRDbSV9ABk8tTADlnACNMYhAAZnDSAAdUIUJzWjtHFzcYuIS6Hz9ApxCwyKNMEzM6BgJmYgJk51dOIpLE8sqCbIDg0OUhCqqa1Prulrbc/K4ASiNUB2JkDikCTCdo1QWAak1wm2RVISFVgEFaAE8AMWIHQgAVI%2BjMDexNGX3u89NVgEkzi4JH/c0Adn0T1WINWaFo3Uw4mixA%2BX0IEAAbqg8OgxqtaKgobNoj9gaCAUD9qCSatBmZkAB9FjdDY2ZGo%2B4QHQANkOp3OVxuHBANFQlM4Yw2RNJoPJeCpNJ%2BmwZ6CZrPZ8II11uIF5qH52iF4RForJFQp1OYtJlKLl4WwzO0bOOSpVPL5lPC2t1IIBABFfh7hV6ngB6P3rd0yTQATk9wc0uhD7s4mgAHHHI7p9MmAKyaZPcTNx%2BPhHMJh6xhNJ3M2IMh3RF3PaCtRv7J1OVmO50slzPNgC0Haj8Z7ugjNf7GeL8ZbCez6f7oYLif7MlIdd0J37RcrTajMcr%2BeT4/jJ0Xs/%2Bs%2B0q6Xtf7EcrI8r5f7K9HW6ja97/ePyZfuhnWeHJ6XD9zJ8q37U8p0ffsG2bX4XgcN5mGiZZMFWEA4U5aUbHgxD7kJX4QVlVZHU4CAhUBb18Xwx1tGInD/k9fEA1WCiNSdajSNopdJ2vfsN2jX9kzvZNQMrPss0PUd3yHD8lyvKM0yDQC%2BKgxt%2BxEyt30rT8hM3S95yXT9OKjGToyXVSo3%2BeSJ1nHdKyMhtcxZFTpy9WifSeaCCFeAhViCNRfOQ1DvjpHzaF87DSPIs0COYoiSP0FyItRKLNVYuK6OJRjIsdcIUrIv4XJ1X0/ieXwvKcZhfGI9ZwvSzD2FWZhXPS4K/KCRrcPqgA6QjqIK/Egi66Ket1ANmAG/lspdOtQ0g59%2B24JcZuA/j70c5TkxEhTR2s2ST1nNt9zErjRyTdcVOkvia3PWcePU2bBN0nSwM2o6lNO9a31XED50emzPuTUMLPjSdc22gcINnBz3vWjrnPdKQJlYaQ03kVxZHkVBpBsAwDDJKYZiQnRwk4eQCGkOQxgmABrEA0wXRGpG4FGyfR6R5CEEAF1JtGJjgWAYEQFBUCWPB2DICgIDQYXRZAYBOE4dwqBFhZiHZiAgmZ0ggl8SojmkYnSElpwrAIAB5WhWF1tHSCwMr1HYDX8GITBTDwRFMHZq2oWdhwFj1%2BQSuKDXWDwIJiB1uwsA1jy8CcP2JioVRgCEAA1PBMAAdxN25Uf1/hGBYe2eD4OgCGEMRJCtpR6lUdQUGxvQVBD9nIAmVBcUSD3OwAdTYVhVm7250DUCl%2B670JiBINnimd0pXAgTw%2BjqDxrGGDownqWJ4lnxflE3zJaFXvJOgGaeXbKHpqnsWoulP2fmiqQ/RgGC%2Bd%2BfoZfHaI/14mIQ8dmcYVBIyZlbDGUhxDxhZJ2Fk81gDIGQKsOWHVawQCxnoAwi5cCEBIOsbQRNFx2ClqEHBRMxgk2ZhTUg1NaaAIZvIWO1DUZyFIKAtmHNSBc3JqQXmAspgEGiD7cglBJbRBFsfDw%2BAiDr2LvQJgbAOBFzzmXCQGt05h2iHHGhyNSCMJZlIE2Pt%2BFeVQFQVY4DIHQNWLA%2BBiDkEEJEaLYhgoyHcwmAgTAzAsBhGIjQxmpB6ELh0cw1mRg2EcPhlTGmdNpDhGAUwlh7DyEI2kNoWJujnHkwmG7FWiQQDcCAA%3D%3D%3D)